# Are node.js data structures volatile/when to use a database over data structure?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, volatile

I am considering using node.js to build an API like service but am having trouble understanding whether to use a data structure vs. storing information in a database/text file.

Basically the program would allow for a user to come on line and collect that users geo-coded location. Then the service would store that information in either a javascript data structure or store it into a database or text file. Then another user would log on and I would connect them with a user who is closes to them.

My question is, if I have a datastructure (some sort of custom implemented sorted list based off of geo-codes) would all of that information be volatile and I would loose it if the program crashed?

Would it be more preferable to store the information in a text file or database even though the access and write of that information would take longer?

Also, if I was using the data structure approach, would that make it more difficult to scale the application if I needed to expand to additional servers?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, if I have a datastructure (some sort of custom
>   implemented sorted list based off of geo-codes) would all of that
>   information be volatile and I would loose it if the program crashed?

Yes, it would be volatile and you would lose it if the program crashed.  All Javascript data is kept in RAM.

> Would it be more preferable to store the information in a text file or
>   database even though the access and write of that information would
>   take longer?

When exactly to save data to a persistent store is highly dependent upon the details of the situation.  You could have only a disk store or you could have a RAM store that is periodically stored to disk or you could have a combination (a RAM cache in front of a persistent store).  Using a database will generally do a lot of caching for you.

> Also, if I was using the data structure approach, would that make it
>   more difficult to scale the application if I needed to expand to
>   additional servers?

If you want to share a live data store among multiple servers, then you have to use something other than just Javascript data stored in node.js memory.  The usual solution is to go with some sort of external database which itself can be either in-memory (like Redis) or disk-store (like Mongo or Couchbase) which all the different servers can then access.